# How Do you Randomly Select a line in a textfile, display it on a label and remove from list?

Tags: c#, random, display

I want to select a line randomly in my text file nd display it on a label and remove it so it cant be seen again unless the text file has ran out of lines, I know how to read in but not display a random line and remove it...

For reference I am creating a game and on my splash I am displaying tips and removing each time its been displayed but ill do a count on each time its removed and clear the list if there is nothing left...

```
               void trsting()
    {
        List<string> facts = new List<string>();

        Random r = new Random();

        StreamReader factr = new StreamReader("MarioBrosFacts.txt");

        string line = "";

        while (!factr.EndOfStream)
        {
            line = factr.ReadLine();
            facts.Add(line);
        }

        label2.Text = "Fun Fact:  " + facts[r.Next(1, facts.Count)];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if the text file is not very big, here is the simple solution

```
    private void DoJob()
    {
        List<string> data= System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\MarioBrosFacts.txt").ToList();
        while (data.Count()>0)
        {
            int line = new Random().Next(1,data.Count())-1;
            MarioBrosClass.MarioBrosFact.Add(data[line]);
            data.RemoveAt(line);
        }

    }
```

if you want to show the lines in the label you have to use thread and invoke method to avoid of form hanging

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread tr = new Thread(() => DoJob());
        tr.Start();
    }

    private void DoJob()
    {
        List<string> MarioBrosFact = new List<string>();
        List<string> data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\MarioBrosFacts.txt").ToList();
        while (data.Count() > 0)
        {
            int line = new Random().Next(1,data.Count()) - 1;
            MarioBrosFact.Add(data[line]);
            this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                label1.Text = data[line];
            }));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            data.RemoveAt(line);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ok Thanks Very much for the response but if i want to display it in the label where do i include that (label2)

Comment: as you know the loop speed is very high, and you only can see the last value at the end of iteration.

Comment: use the value '1' as first parameter in random function, the code has been updated.

Comment: So it displays and works perfectly although i use a timer on my form and when using system.threading it is causing an issue, i have found another method that displays it but doesnt remove it... do you want me to show you that code and you can show me how to remove it?

Comment: absolutely. here is my email address: hjolany@gmail.com

Comment: Hello, Thanks for you time for trying to help, i edited the original code with the new one :)

Comment: Move the `Random` declaration to outside the while loop and re-use the same instance, as in `Random R = new Random();`.  Then, instead of passing 1 and subtracting 1 in your line selection, just do `int line = R.Next(data.Count());`.  You don't need `MarioBrosFact` at all.

Comment: Ok thanks very much for that! Now Works as a charm but how do i add them all back in the list when all have been removed, i would usually do a count then clear the list and add it back...